# Edit Datagridview row item in another form (Master-Detail)

Tags: c#, data-binding

In my c# (VS2008) application i have 2 winforms. In Form1, there is a DataGridView which shows a list of "Employee" objects. This datagridview is databound to EmployeeList BindingSource. In Form2, controls are bound to Employee bindingsource.

I am being able to add Employee from Form2 to EmployeeList in Form1. What i want is whenever i doubleclick in datagridview, Form2 will open with the selected Employee data. Then updated data will send back to Form1 datagridview. But datagridview is not updated from Form2.

What is the technique to do that.

Thanking in advance.
SKPaul.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

Without any posted code, we won't be able to help with any specific problem, but this is something generic you can try out:

In Form1

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
{
   //update whatever info for that employee
}


private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      DataGridViewCell selectedEmployeeCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]; //Get whatever data you're sending from this to the new form

      Employee tempEmployee = getEmployee(selectedEmployeeCell);

      Form2 updateEmp = new Form2(tempEmployee, this);
      updateEmp.showDialog();
}
```

In Form2

```
    public Form2(Employee emp, Form1 parent)
    {
        //blah blah blah
    }

 private void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    parent.UpdateEmployee(emp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to stay away from using the wizard data source with grid views. I would code the grids by hand and then pass the variables in the url to the second grid using a button in the edit row of the first grid. Or in your case maybe the selected row event of the first grid.